# Deploying node.js application in Amazon Elastic BeansTalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

When i tried deploying node.js application in Amazon Elastic Beans Talk Management Console, the health showed red.

Please check the below error message and kindly advise me to solve the problem.

[image]

[image]

Health
Red

Running Version
SGCP28
Upload and Deploy

Configuration
Node.js

As mentioned above , the health is showing red , what does it mean ? How can we solve that or find out the reason why it is red?

```
Recent Events 
Time                            Type    Details
2014-02-28 10:36:47 UTC+0800    INFO    Deleted log fragments for this environment.
2014-02-28 10:31:49 UTC+0800    INFO    Environment update completed successfully.
2014-02-28 10:31:49 UTC+0800    INFO    Successfully deployed new configuration to                         environment.
2014-02-28 10:30:59 UTC+0800    INFO    Updating environment sg-env's configuration settings.
2014-02-28 10:30:51 UTC+0800    INFO    Environment update is starting.
```

Kindly suggest . Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the logs:

Click on logs on the left, then snapshot logs, then click the link that appears and see what's going on in there.

I haven't used node.js on beanstalk, but it looks like it's expecting your app to exist in a certain file at a certain place in your repo, and you don't have it there.

Comment: In Amazon Web Server , node.js start command for sails.js application , what should we give ?? By default , it will take app.js , server.js or npm start. I dont have any specific code in app.js or server.js..So my application is not running even if i deploy.Please help

Comment: I believe there is an environment variable you can set to tell beanstalk where to find your app to start it.  Not sure exactly what it is for node.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says "Failed to find package.json." Do you have that configuration file as part of your project? It contains the app start configuration:

Ex:

```
...
"scripts": {
    "start": "node app.js"
},
...
```